# ASP.NET Identity remember email address on login page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, remember-me

Asp.Net Identity introduces "remember me" functionality. However my requirement is only to remember email address on the login form, not to login user permanently. So once the user comes back, has to provide his password only. If other user tries to login, he will have to provide his email as well.

Has Asp.Net Identity some built-in functionality I could base on or shall I implement this functionality completely on my own from the scratch?

I use Asp.Net Identity v2.2.1.

Comment: Thanks for stopping by to let us know your plan. What are you going to do to make this happen? Or, what have you done so far?

Comment: Sounds great, I say go ahead and do it!

Comment: @R.Richards I went through available documentation to check if such functionality is available. As couldn't find it, shall I implement this completely on my own, or there is some Asp.Net Identity built-in functionality I can base on?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, no. You could just save the email in a cookie, or the browser local storage, when the end user has said they want it saved for later, then pull it when you need to. Thanks for adding a question to your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As R. Richards said, you should go with cookie in your case because they are great when storing per-user information for the current Web session or persistent information on the client.

[Here's](https://blog.codeinside.eu/2010/10/19/howto-create-and-remove-cookies-with-asp-net-mvc/) an helpful link that shows basic implementation of a cookie in asp.net c#

Hope this help! Feel free to ask for more information.